# SKTextureAtlas no longer sharing textures in iOS 10

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios10

It seems that when pulling textures from a texture atlas, I am now generating new textures instead of using the same texture across different sprites with iOS 10.  On iOS 9, this works as expected.  Is anyone else experiencing this issue?  Perhaps there is a step I missed that is now a part of iOS 10.

Notes: I created a sample project and created a new atlas, then just dragged spaceship in @1x,  I have also tried preloading, and that did nothing as well.

Code:

```
  let atlas = SKTexturAtlas(named:"Sprites")
  var texture = atlas.textureNamed("Spaceship")
  print("\(Unmanaged.passUnretained(texture)),\(Unmanaged.passUnretained(texture).toOpaque())")

  texture = atlas.textureNamed("Spaceship")
  print("\(Unmanaged.passUnretained(texture)),\(Unmanaged.passUnretained(texture).toOpaque())")
```

Edit: To get around issues of comparison,  I use the description property to compare if 2 textures are equal.  For this to work though, you can't be using 2 atlases that each contain a texture with an exact name and size.  I will never hit this situation, but for anybody out there looking for help, keep this in mind.

Comment: Oh, interesting question, iOS10 never ceases to amaze..

Comment: Between this and creating SkPhysicsBodies(textures) taking 10x as long they really screwed me over

Comment: So, finally...BOOM! This is real bug :-( ... this makes me think a lot about latest slowness during my game (after playing 20 levels) only in iOS 10..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around this issue, I had to come up with a way to cache the textures so that it doesn't duplicate:

```
private var textureCache = [String: SKTexture]()
extension SKTextureAtlas
{
    func texturesWithNames(_ names:[String]) -> [SKTexture]
    {
        var textures = [SKTexture]()
        names.forEach({textures.append(textureNamed($0))})
        return textures
    }
    func cachedTextureWithName(_ name:String) -> SKTexture
    {
        if  textureCache[name] == nil
        {

            textureCache[name] = textureNamed(name)
        }

        return textureCache[name]!
    }
    func cachedTexturesWithNames(_ names:[String]) -> [SKTexture]
    {
        var textures = [SKTexture]()
        names.forEach({textures.append(cachedTextureWithName($0))})
        return textures
    }
    func clearCache()
    {
        textureCache = [String: SKTexture]()
    }
}


extension SKTexture
{

    var name : String
    {
        return self.description.slice(start: "'",to: "'")!
    }


}
```

Comment: Great workaround. I suppose that after getting/creating an instance of `SKTextureAtlas`, one would have to call `cachedTexturesWithNames:` with the array of `textureNames` from atlas, in order to get them cached, right?

Comment: yes, from here on out, you would only use cachedTexturesWithNames.  If you plan on using sks building, you need to override SKSpriteNode's init to handle the caching call as well

Comment: I provided the extension to get the name from a texture as well incase you needed it

Comment: I see. Which is really sad, since everywhere we use `SKTexture(imageNamed:)`, we will have to instead access an already cached `SKTexture` directly from atlas by the new texture's `name` property you defined. Which also means that we will have to use `SKTexturAtlas(named:)` every time before getting a hold of a texture. Is that how you do it as well or do you store a reference to the atlas in a global property and access the textures from there?

Comment: `SKTexture(imageNamed:)` always made a new instance,  if you want you can write an extension to grab it from the atlas as well.

Comment: True. I just liked how decoupled `SKTexture` was from `SKTextureAtlas` when SpriteKit actually worked. :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I've make the same test and get your same results.

I'm not sure 100% but seems that during  the development of Swift 3 there was a proposal [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRubY.png) to change **Unmanaged** to use **UnsafePointer**.

But if you try to make:

```
func address<T: AnyObject>(o: T) -> String{
     let addr = unsafeBitCast(o, to: Int.self)
     return NSString(format: "%p", addr) as String
}
```

**Usage**:

```
print(address(o: texture))
```

in **iOS9** you have correct values, in **iOS10** wrong results.

[image]

I think you're right, we are facing a bug (another..)

Comment: hmm this may be grabbing the pointer of texture variable, not  the instance that it is holding if that makes sense.  make a new texture called texture2, and you will see the address change by 4 bytes

Answer (score 1):

Is having a different physical address for a texture referencing the "same texture" really a problem?

I've run the default sample game project, but setup for Obj-C. I have a texture atlas that would be something like the image below. However, note that I ran that through TexturePacker. So the actual generated atlas by Xcode is different.

[image]

I do as you said and created 2 textures with the same name.

```
self.myTextureAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"MyTexture"];
self.tex0 = [self.myTextureAtlas textureNamed:@"tex0"];
self.tex1 = [self.myTextureAtlas textureNamed:@"tex0"];
```

As you said, the pointers for `tex0` and `tex1` are different. So at least there is consistency between Swift and Obj-C.

However, I don't think this is a problem/bug. What I suspect is that that they changed implementation so the returned `SKTexture` is a new "instance", however the underlying texture is still the same.

I'll talk OpenGL, since that is what I write my engines in. Metal will still have similarities. A basic sub-texture really has only 2 important properties: a texture name (this is the OpenGL texture name) and UVs. If you were thinking about what would be considered the "equality" for conforming to `Equatable`, it would most likely be testing for equality against those 2 items. The texture name is the atlas texture name, and the UVs are the UVs within the atlas which represent the area of the particular sub-texture.

To test this hypothesis, I ran a GPU frame capture on this. With Xcode 8 this seems pretty buggy. Using Metal, it crashed 100% of the time. I forced it to use OpenGL and managed to get a frame capture. As expected when I looked at all texture resources, I see only one texture for my atlas.

[image]

Texture #3 is MyTexture.

If I dump the textureRect, which appear to be the UVs, I can see they are the same:

> Tex0 Rect 0.001618 0.793765 0.139159 0.203837
>
> Tex1 Rect 0.001618 0.793765 0.139159 0.203837

Based on this, it would seem that both `self.tex0` and `self.tex1`, although having different physical addresses, still both point to the same sub-texture.

Note that I no longer use SpriteKit. My current renderer uses handles for textures, however, when retrieved, you can get handle objects with different physical addresses. They still all dereference to the true texture since they still reference the same underlying texture instance.

I guess, I don't really see getting diff pointers a problem provided they still reference the same underlying texture (ie. no more texture memory is allocated).

Comment: No more texture memory may be allocated, but more physical memory is allocated, and it is allocated at the time of the call, which means it now takes longer.  It is also no longer equatable, and now has a new hash value on every instance, so I can no longer use the SKTexture as a key, which is a problem for me since I need to find someway to grab SKPhysicsBodies that are pre-created based on the texture because of SKPhysicsBody(texture) now taking 10x as long, there by blowing up the loading time to my game.  What took 4 seconds now takes 90 seconds or more (Other slowdowns exist too)

Comment: This is a huge change from iOS 9

Comment: That really sucks. As I don't know how you are doing things, why are you needing to grab a texture via the `textureNamed` call? Would it be possible for you to use some form of texture manager to vend the texture as opposed to using `textureNamed`? If you have the same physically addressed `SKTexture` does `SKPhysicsBody` still have adverse affects?

Comment: how else do you grab a texture for an atlas other than `textureNamed`?  Having the same physical address(or any way to compare 2 SKTextures) would allow me to store PhysicsBodies into a container, so if I have 2 sprites that have the same texture, I can pull a copy of the same physics body instead of having to create a new  physics body every time with the texture method (pixel accuracy is important, so rectangle comparison is not acceptable for me)

Comment: That is why I mentioned about a texture manager. You would have the texture manager create the `SKTexture` and give it back to you any time you need it. You could alternately wrap the `SKTexture` in another object. When I did use SpriteKit, I did both.

Comment: The thing  with a texture manager is it requires me to not use the SpriteKit editor, or reload all sprites with new textures that are in this texture manager. I am trying to avoid refactoring all my code if I can, I know a lot of people here read all the detailed docs and discussions on the new changes,  and I was hoping someone could shed some light on the matter in case Apple left something in there to allow the old method.  Plus it allows people to know that this change happened, because I know I have answered a lot of questions with comparing `SKTexture`, and these answers are now wrong.

Comment: There's so few users of SpriteKit that you might need to use a support ticket to get this more rapidly addressed. @Knight0fDragon. Huge pity. The potential for lightweight gaming frameworks specific to iOS/tvOS/macOS/watchOS is huge. The reality of SK and SCN leaves a lot to be desired.