# FPS continuously dropping when restarting the game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene, frame-rate

I am building a new game in SpriteKit and each time I want to restart the game I switch scenes, therefore each time I press "play again" my GameScene is loaded from the beginning and this causes my FPS to continuously drop.

So this is causing my FPS to drop overtime since each time I press play I have to basically load the whole new GameScene and the game on it (which is mostly spawning nodes). I believe that if there is no way in capping the FPS at a certain rate, then I should not use transitioning between 2 scenes.

However, I tried the method where I keep everything in 1 scene but unfortunately it did not work out since each time I pressed restart, the amounts of SKSpriteNodes that were spawning doubled. So the spawning of nodes and my timer speeds up by 2 times each time I play again. I don't know how to figure this issue out.

Answer (score 5):

Everytime you change the scene , it should be removed from memory with its children.

You can add this method at the end of your scene:

```
deinit {
    print("\n THE SCENE \(type(of: self))) WAS REMOVED FROM MEMORY (DEINIT) \n")
}
```

If you don't see in you debug console this print maybe you have a strong reference to self somewhere in your code.
You can follow the official guide to ["Resolving Strong Reference Cycles for Closures"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID57)

Comment: Also I would add that we should always have in mind that offscreen nodes should be removed, because otherwise they still live in a node tree and eat resources.

Comment: @Whirlwind,  I wouldn't say always removed, there may be times when physics are applying off screen,  depends on the game.  But yes, if the node is not going to have interaction of any kind off screen, then it should be removed.  Even though the node count drops on the screen,  this is only showing the drawing count, not the amount of nodes in the tree

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't complety precise about this. Nodes that are off screen, and not needed, should be removed from a node tree. But I thought this doesn't have to be mentioned because it already implies. @Knight0fDragon

Comment: @Whirlwind people are impressionable,  I have been learning more and more from people asking me questions to be more concise.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I do remove the children every time I change the screen and I also remove the nodes each time they pass the screen but I am not sure if I remove it from the memory, Can someone let me know please how to remove stuff from the memory, because my lags might be a happening due to CPU Usage or because I keep saving stuff on my memory. Thank You!

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano and yes, I do not see the print of that.

Comment: @user7208112 As I said if you see this print in my code your SKScene and its children were removed. There is no need to remove manually all the childrens because this is the work of Automatic Reference Counting. You must resolve strong references to self if there are. About memory you can launch File-Open Developer Tool-Instruments where you can monitor your memory status..

Comment: @user7208112 If you have always difficults to remove strong references please add some code so we can help you ;-)

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I actually figured out how to delete my memory after moving form one scene to another. I use: override func wullMoveFrom view { self.removeAllChildren(). self.removeAllActions().    }                                                                                                               However after a while, for some reason my FPS still drops down, after a longer time now but it still does. My deinit print is displayed now, but for some reason my FPS still drops down after a while and I really don't know what  could be causing it at this point. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @user7208112 Assuming you have correctly spawn a good number of object according to a mobile game (in other words respecting the RAM dimension), there is another SpriteKit bug reported by Knight0fDragon here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307075/sktextureatlas-no-longer-sharing-textures-in-ios-10/40308931#40308931 that could be the cause of a FPS collapse and could help you to deeply understand your issue. BTW, you are in the right way to solve..